# Variable importance

Tags: regression, logistic, cart

I am learning decision tree and there is variable importance which measures the total drop in MSE thanks to that variable. I am wondering whether variable importance or something similar exists in linear/logistic regression?

Comment: https://topepo.github.io/caret/variable-importance.html

Comment: https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v017i01